# How to extract the third column using grep?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

How can I use `grep` to get only the third level ids?

```
"id": 2,
      "id": 12,
          "id": 136,
          "id": 229,
          "id": 230,
          "id": 231,
          "id": 232,
          "id": 233,
          "id": 234,
```

I want to get only:

```
136
229
230
231
232
233
234
```

I tried different approaches with grep and cut.

Comment: If the file is always in the same format, you could first cut the two lines with 'sed 1,2d <filename>' and then grep the numbers from it using awk or sed.

Comment: What is the data structured as? yaml?

Comment: No, plain text.

Comment: are the 2nd level entries always indented 6 spaces? and the 3rd level entries indented a total of 10 spaces? are there other tags (besides `"id"`) in the file?  do you **have** to use `grep` or is some other command/tool acceptable?  what `grep` (or other) commands have you tried so far?

Comment: there are no other tags than "id", and the indentations are consistent throughout the file (2nd level 6, 3rd level 10 spaces).

Comment: I tried grep and cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions and collection of OPs comments:

- lines of interest start with 10 spaces
- only tags in the file are `"id"`
- only values of interest are unquoted integers
- anything following an unquoted integer is ignored

Sample data:

```
$ cat id.dat
"id": 2,
      "id": 12,
          "id": 136,
          "id": 229,
          "id": 230,
          "id": 231,
          "id": 232,
          "id": ,                 # not a match
          "id": 233,
          "id": abcd,             # not a match
          "id": 234,
          "id": "999",            # not a match
          "id": 123456.77,        # only match on "123456"
```

One `grep` idea:

```
grep -Po '^ {10}"id": \K[0-9]+' id.dat
```

Where:

- `-Po` - enable perl regexp support, only output matching strings
- `^ {10}"id":`  - lines of interest start with `10 spaces` + `"id:"` + `1 space`
- `\K` - exclude preceding pattern (aka look-behind) match from output
- `[0-9]+` - match 1 or more numbers (anything other than contiguous numbers from here to the end of the line are ignored)

The above generates:

```
136
229
230
231
232
233
234
123456
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Other answers are good, as well, but since I'm currently learning to grep, I wanted a grep solution.

Comment: @MateMrše just be aware that this solution requires GNU grep so if/when you do the same on a different platform that has a different version of grep, it will fail. IMHO you'd be better off using a simple, portable awk or sed solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk to extract numeric values (since `$NF+0` to remove the comma):

```
$ awk '/^ {10}/{print $NF+0}' file
```

Output:

```
136
229
230
...
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/^ {10}/ {        # records started by (at least) 10 spaces
    print $NF+0   # print the numeric value from the last field
}' file
```

Will need tweaking if the values are not numeric or if there are 4th level ids:

```
$ awk '
/^ {10}[^ ]/ {     # starts with exactly 10 spaces
    sub(/,$/,"")   # remove comma from the end
    print $NF      # output last awk default defined field
}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/ \{10\}.* \([^ ,]*\).*/\1/p' file
136
229
230
231
232
233
234
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, with shown samples, considering that your spaces for id are in increasing order only and starting `id` line will NOT be starting from a space as per shown sample. This solution doesn't hard code number of spaces in it and this should take care of multiple lines with `id` os same spaces too.

```
awk '
/id/ && match($0,/^ +/){
  spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
prev!=spaces && /id/{
  found=""
  if(++count==2){
    found=1
  }
}
{
  prev=spaces
}
found{
  val=(val?val ",":"")$NF+0
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one, using gawk:

`gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="11 2 3 3"  '$2=="id"{ print $4 }' inputfile`

from the 'man'-page:

> If the FIELDWIDTHS variable is set to a space-separated list of numbers, each field is expected to have  fixed  width,  and gawk splits up the record using the specified widths.

Answer (score 1):

You could go through the file, line by line, cut out what is needed and check if the value you are looking for is 3 numbers long and then print it out, disregarding the others:

```
 #!/bin/bash


for i in $(cat filename | sed 's/^.*: //; s/,.*$//');

do

    if  [[ $(( "length $i" )) == 3 ]];
    then
            echo "$i"
 fi
done
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net  and it'll tell you about several issues. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html for other issues.